# is there a way to "multicast" a request with haproxy?

Tags: haproxy, multicast

I have a configuration with a cloud of servers behind haproxy. Haproxy is loadbalancing between the servers. However there's some action that needs to be sent to each server. Currently I do it independently from haproxy, by going to each server in a loop:

```
for i in `seq 1-10`; do
  wget -O /dev/null "http://server$i.local.exampe.com/clear/cache"
done
```

is it possible to set up haproxy so that

```
wget -O /dev/null "http://server.exampe.com/clear/cache"
```

could send the request out to every server that is alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have seen this is not supported in HAProxy an probably won't ever be. There is a [similar question asked on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg02138.html) (still 1->N) answered by [Willy](http://stackexchange.com/users/84974/willy-tarreau) mentioning that this isn't load balancing which is why it won't be supported. You could also try a pub-sub mechanism instead of sequentially hitting each server.